Godot: Target position of Ball changes upon calling new instance
I'm working on Breakout which is a game with a ball and you use a paddle to hit some bricks with the ball.
My starting position of the ball is in the middle of the screen and as soon as the game begins, the ball shoots downwards toward the paddle. I also have a script on the bottom wall of the main scene which resets the ball (and player loses a life) if it touches.
extends CharacterBody2D

var speed: int = 3

func _ready():
    var target_position = Vector2(575, 645)
    var direction = global_position.direction_to(target_position)
    velocity = direction.normalized() * speed

func _physics_process(delta):
    var collision = move_and_collide(velocity)
    
    if collision != null:
        velocity = velocity.bounce(collision.get_normal())
        if collision.get_collider().has_method("hit"):
            collision.get_collider().hit()

This is the script for my Ball scene. The ball is placed in the middle of the main scene at position (575, 450). Upon starting it heads towards position (575, 645) which is below the paddle.
And for my main scene, I have this code.
extends Node2D

var current_ball
var ball_scene = preload("res://scenes/ball.tscn")

func _on_bottom_wall_body_entered(body):
    reset_ball()
    
func _ready():
    current_ball = $Ball
    ball_position()
    
func _physics_process(delta):
    $Label.text = str(Globals.score)
    
func reset_ball():
    if current_ball:
        current_ball.queue_free()
    current_ball = ball_scene.instantiate()
    await get_tree().create_timer(3).timeout
    add_child(current_ball)
    ball_position()

func ball_position():
    current_ball.position.x = 575
    current_ball.position.y = 450

The bottom area is an Area2D and when the ball enters, it resets back to the middle and is meant to head straight downwards again towards the paddle.
The problem that I'm having is that as soon as the ball starts moving after being reset, the position of the direction changes from (575, 645) to (748, 644) and I have no idea why that's happening. So instead of heading downwards toward the paddle, it slightly rotates and starts heading to the right of the screen where it will hit the Area2D again.

Switch add_child and ball_position in the reset_ball function.
func reset_ball():
    if current_ball:
        current_ball.queue_free()
    current_ball = ball_scene.instantiate()
    await get_tree().create_timer(3).timeout
    ball_position()
    add_child(current_ball)

Adding the ball to the scene will call it's ready function. In which you calculate the target direction it should move to. Since you did not change it's position first, it will calculate the direction from Vector2(0,0) instead of your default start position (575,450).
After adding it to the scene you were changing its position so it gets teleported to 575,450 and then moves into the direction calculated in the ready function.
Switching these two calls will change the calulated direction
